# Name for trope where a POV character has someone hanging out in their mind?

Tags: telepathy, terminology, trope

I've seen this trope in a lot of different media, where a telepathic being (not necessarily capable of telepathy with anyone, this can be limited to the one character) is just sort of hanging out in the mind of the POV character, holding silent conversations with them, usually commenting on things happening. Darkstalker from Wings of Fire and the Squip from BMC are good examples, but there are a ton more.

Does this trope have a name?

Comment: Trope identification seems to be very opinion-based

Comment: From TVTropes, we get "[Mind Hive](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MindHive)".

Comment: So you mean specifically that the presence in their mind is a real *other* living telepathic being, and *not* their memory of someone / a facet of their own personality? So *not* what happens in, say, Crazy Ex-Girlfriend, or Flight Attendant?